# Magento2: Table border and hover

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have created simple css table.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table tr {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}

table tr:hover {
    background-color: #3b458e;
    }

table th,
table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }

  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  table td::before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">SKU</th>
      <th scope="col">Image</th>
      <th scope="col">EAN</th>
      <th scope="col">Brand</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Size</th>
      <th scope="col">Leadtime</th>
      <th scope="col">MSRP</th>
      <th scope="col">Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Qty</th>
      <th scope="col">Total</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Account">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Account">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Account">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">04/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,190</td>
      <td data-label="Period">03/01/2016 - 03/31/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Account">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Account">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Account">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Account">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Account">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Account">Visa - 3412</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Acount">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">02/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$842</td>
      <td data-label="Period">01/01/2016 - 01/31/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">02/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">02/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">02/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">02/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">02/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">02/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">02/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">02/01/2016</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Result:
[image]

1. How to removing the top, left and right border. (I want to leave only the bottom border)
   [image]
2. Currently table head is hover, and td is hover:

head hover effect:
[image]

td hover effect:
[image]

I want delete head hover effect. I need only td hover effect. Can anyone help me correct this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.
What I changed:

1. removed border from everywhere, and just added `border-bottom` property to table row.
2. removed hover background from thead by adding `table thead tr:hover` with `background:#fff;`

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table tr {
  background-color: white;
  padding: .35em;
  border-bottom: 1px #cdcdcd solid;
}


table tr:hover {
    background-color: #3b458e;
}
    
table thead tr:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }

  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  table td::before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```